# Capturing image frames in YUV_420_888 format using ImageReader in Camera API 2 not giving correct results in dual camera devices

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm working on an android app which takes image input from camera preview in YUV_420_888 format and converts it into its RGB equivalent. It is a heart beat measuring app which takes red color frames from user's finger tip when the user touches the camera surface. The camera implementation is done using Camera API 2 and the images frames are captured using ImageReader whose format is set to YUV_420_888.

```
imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(smallest.getWidth(), smallest.getHeight(), ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 1);
```

The image frames captured in YUV_420_888 format is then converted into RGB using the following function:

```
public static double[] decodeYUV420SP_888toRedBlueGreenAvg(byte[] Y1, byte[] U1, byte[] V1, int width, int height) {


    int Width = width;
    int Height = height;
    byte[] ImageRGB = new byte[Width*Height*4];

    double[] rgb =new double[3];
    for(int i = 0; i<Height-1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<Width; j++){
            int Y = Y1[i*Width+j]&0xFF -16;
            int U = U1[(i/2)*(Width/2)+j/2]&0xFF;
            int V = V1[(i/2)*(Width/2)+j/2]&0xFF;
            U = U-128;
            V = V-128;
            int R,G,B;

            /*R = (int) (Y + 1.402*(V-128));
            G = (int) (Y - 0.34414 *(U-128) - 0.71414 *(V-128));
            B = (int) (Y + 1.772 *(U-128));*/

           //correct values
            R = (int)(Y + 1.140*V);
            G = (int)(Y - 0.395*U - 0.581*V);
            B = (int)(Y + 2.032*U);



            /*int y1192 = 1192 * Y;
            R = (y1192 + 1634 * V);
            G = (y1192 - 833 * V - 400 * U);
            B = (y1192 + 2066 * U);*/


          /*  Y_temp = 4768 * (Y - 16);
            R = (Y_temp + 6537 * (V - 128)) >> 12;
            G = (Y_temp - 3330 * (V - 128) - 1602 * (U - 128)) >> 12;
            B = (Y_temp + 8266 * (U - 128)) >> 12;*/

          //test
            if (R>255) {
                R = 255;
            } else if (R<0) {
                R = 0;
            }
            if (G>255) {
                G = 255;
            } else if (G<0) {
                G = 0;
            }
            if (B>255) {
                R = 255;
            } else if (B<0) {
                B = 0;
            }


            ImageRGB[i*4*Width+j*4] = (byte)R;
            ImageRGB[i*4*Width+j*4+1] = (byte)G;
            ImageRGB[i*4*Width+j*4+2] = (byte)B;
            ImageRGB[i*4*Width+j*4+3] = -1;
            rgb[0] = R;
            rgb[1] = G;
            rgb[2] = B;
        }
    }


    return rgb;}
```

The image saver class is as follows:

```
 private class ImageSaver implements Runnable {

    byte[] y1, u1, v1;
    int width, height;

    public ImageSaver(byte[] y1, byte[] u1, byte[] v1, int width, int height) {
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.u1 = u1;
        this.v1 = v1;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //if data or size == null ****


        if (y1 == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();


        if (textureView == null) throw new NullPointerException();

        current value == the expected value.
        if (!processing.compareAndSet(false, true)) return;


        //put width + height of the camera inside the variables
        int width = textureView.getWidth();
        int height = textureView.getHeight();
        RGBAvg = YUVtoRGB.decodeYUV420SP_888toRedBlueGreenAvg(y1, u1, v1, width, height);
```

Then some processing is done using the rgb values.
This is working fine for single camera devices but for dual camera device the rgb values are coming as green colors rather than red. Especially in Oppo and few Redmi devices devices such as Oppo F9 pro and Redmi 6 pro.

Any help will be highly appreciated!